# Music players with visualzers

Tags: music-player

Are there any music players that have good visualizers that can be displayed full screen other than ncmpcpp?

Answer (score 0):

Try [projectM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/projectM) which works for any PulseAudio app.

If it helps, Amarok has a plugin for it, as does [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) now (which I wrote).